# PHPWord name spaces / classes & functions

Tags: php, phpword

I'm aware this might be more a question of understanding PHP Namespaces,etc...but I still can't get my head around the following:
I have an MVC controller with the below usages:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Paper;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Language;
```

...and the following function:

```
public function word(){
$phpword= new PhpWord();

$settings=$phpword->getSettings();

//$languageFrFr = new Language('FR_FR');
//$settings->setThemeFontLang($languageFrFr);

$docInfo=$phpword->getDocInfo();
$docInfo->setCreator('JMB');
$docInfo->setCreated(date("d-m-Y"));

$paper = new Paper();
$paper->setSize( 'A4' );

$section = $phpword->addSection();
$section->addText('An example dummy text...');
$file = 'test.docx';
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpword, 'Word2007');
$xmlWriter->save("php://output");
```

This works perfectly (eg the WORD file & it's content are output correctly...
UNTIL...I uncomment & try to set the 'ThemeFontLang' : function hangs when I load:

```
$languageFrFr = new Language('FR_FR');
```

Any clue why this is happening, and how I could avoid / bypass the long paths\namespaces definitions  inside my function ?
Many thanks,
JMB

Comment: Check your webserver logs, it should contain whatever PHP errors are causing the hang.

Comment: HI,
No problems in the logs, apparently...
Am still not understanding whta can cause this behavior ...